# Lock screen on corner action (with timeout)

Tags: display, hot-corners

I have installed Elementary OS on my iMac 5k (17.1) and it looks stunning. However I'm missing a feature from macOS that I grew quite fond of. When I move the mouse into a corner of my Desktop the screen is turned of (not locked!!). I do this frequently to save energy. But I don't want this to happen immediately but after a minor timeout (500ms) so the screen does not turn dark when I move the mouse the the corner accidentally (for instance when trying to shut the computer down).

Is this possible with hot-actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and play with xbacklight.
Not sure if it's already installed in Elementary.

```
sudo apt install xbacklight
```

Add a custom command to your desired corner. Something like:

```
xbacklight -dec 100 -time 500
```

This should do the trick.
I can't test it atm, but it should work. If you have any issues, just check xbacklight manual `#man xbacklight`.

Comment: Hello & thank you for your input. `xbacklight` was not installed, but `apt get` sure enough did the trick. Unfortunately the iMac 5k does not support xbacklight. The output of `xbacklight -get` is null (empty).
Besides, this would only fade the brightness within the specified 500ms. What I aimed for was activating the script only when the mouse stays in the corner for more than 500ms (or any other customizable value).